# Is there a way a unit test can access the output to assert?

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there a way for a unit test to access the output a unit test might produce?

I'm trying to test a command object that doesn't return anything but it does produce output through Console.WriteLine.

```
CreateUser userToCreateCommand = new CreateUser 
{
  UserName = "testUser"
}

userToCreateCommand.Execute();

//-> User created: true
//means the user was created successfully.
```

I want to `assert` that the result was **true**

Comment: Typically you'd mock the *output* your command is doing and make sure the [*mocked output* receives the method call from the command](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/).

Comment: What's the reason for printing a message to indicate success rather than using a `bool` return type? Using a return type makes it easier to test, it's a contained unit and your API is straightforward to understand instead of hiding some success/fail message in `stdout`.